# Equivalence relation homeomorphisms

Tags: general-topology, relations

Is said to be $X\approx Y$ ($X$ is homeomorphic to $Y$) iff exists a function $h: X \longrightarrow Y$ which is bijective and preserves open sets, this relationship is an equivalence relation on $Top$ (the set of all topologies).

For a set with cofinite topology (the sets are open if its complement is finite) also happens, i.e if there is a homeomorphism $h:(X,cofinite) \longrightarrow (Y,\mathcal{J})$, must be $\mathcal{J}$ the topology of cofinite?

Comment: So, what is your question, exactly?

Comment: if there is a homeomorphism of $h: (X, cofinite) \longrightarrow (Y, \mathcal{J}) $, must be $\mathcal{J}$ the topology of cofinite?

Comment: Incidentally (pardon me for getting a bit pedantic), $Top$ is the [class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(set_theory)) or [category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory) of all topological spaces. It is not a set.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Only finite subsets of $Y$ are closed, and any homeomorphism maps closed (finite) sets precisely to closed (finite) sets. What then can you say about the open sets in $Y$?

Comment: which are the complement and already would have, but as  deduced that closed sets of $Y$ are precisely the finite sets?

Comment: given that homeorphisms are bijections, isn't that quite obvious? $card (U)=card(f(U))$